# How to install debug libraries (like lib*d) into packages in yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

Now I am writing my master theis which is related to embedded system using yocto.
I have an ua-SDK(source code included). I need to install the ua package into `sato-image`, which runs on a Raspberrypi.

First of all, I write a recipe "opcua" like this:

```
SUMMARY = "this is a recipe for building opc-ua sdk package"
LICENSE = "MIT & RCL & OpenSSL & LGPL-3.0 & Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file:///home/yocto/workspace/poky/rpiHouseHello/tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/ua-new/1.0-r0/license-destdir/ua-new/generic_Apache-2.0;md5=89aea4e17d99a7cacdbeed46a0096b10 
SRC_URI = "file:///home/yocto/workspace/poky/rpiHouseHello/downloads/uasdkcppclient-src-linux32-x86-gcc4.5.1-v1.4.2-275.tar.gz"
S = "${WORKDIR}/sdk/src"
DEPENDS += "libxml2 openssl"
inherit cmake  
INSANE_SKIP_ua-new += "dev-deps"
```

The `opcua` package is installed successfully after `$bitbake opcua`. Then I try to add the generated `opcua` package into sato-image by writing another recipe`sato-with-ua` like this

```
DESCRIPTION = ""
IMAGE_FEATURES += "splash package-management x11-base x11-sato ssh-server-openssh hwcodecs dbg-pkgs tools-debug debug-tweaks"
LICENSE = "MIT"
inherit core-image
IMAGE_INSTALL += " ua ua-dbg ua-staticdev ua-dev"
```

it was also installed successfully.  After that I extracted the SDK from this image by using:

`$bitbake sato-with-ua -c populated_sdk`

There is also no problem.  After that I try to check the functionality of this extracted SDK.  My tutor gave me a test project written by c++. I try to build this project in eclipse.

But here comes the problem, Eclipse can not find the debug libraries---lib*d(for example libuabased.a) by linking libraries.  I found that there is `libuabase.a` but no `libuabased.a` in my package.  Location of the package:`/home/yocto/workspace/poky/rpiHouse/tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/opcua/1.0-r0/packages-split`.  In Eclipse, we develop project in debug version so it also needs libraries in debug version.

I'm confused that why yocto installed only release library but not debug library. Both are included in source code. yocto can only install one type?
so I try to modify the opcua recipe to include the debug library into my packages-split. After reading the reference of yocto I added the follows to my recipe "opcua":

```
PACKAGES =+ " ${PN}-alibd ${PN}-solibd"
FILES_${PN}-alibd = "${libdir}/libstackd.so"
FILES_${PN}-solibd = "${libdir}/libuabased.a ${libdir}/libuaclientd.a ${libdir}/libuapkid.a ${libdir}/libxmlparserd.a"
```

After `bitbake opcua` I got the two new packages `${PN}-alibd and ${PN}-solibd` indeed, but both packages are empty.  All of those libraries I listed above are not included.

My first question is that, does this variable `${libdir}` indicate `/usr/lib` of our host machine? I found there is no `lib*d.a` file in that directory. So I think maybe I make a mistake by understanding this variable. what does this  `${libdir}` referred to?

My second question, how to install those debug libraries into my packages after bitbake the recipe? my goal is that I can get those debug libraries in the `sato-with-ua` image `und` then extract the SDK from this image.This SDK included those debug libraries so that I can link them in my Eclipse to develop my project correctly.

i am so sorry that i told a long story. This is the first time i made something related with software. so I beg your appologise.

Comment: Did you try setting up cross compiler tool chain for ARM in eclipse? or you need to build image using only with yocto project environment?

Comment: sir, I wanna set up cross compiler tool chain for ARM in eclipse. This chain should included opcua libraries. but now it only includes libraries like uaclient.a, how to add libraries like uaclientd.a at the same time? Thanks for helping.

Comment: What does your "debug" library `uaclientd.a` contain that's not part of `uaclient.a`?